# writeToFile.WriteLine backspace?

Tags: vb.net

I want to write some text to a .txt file, this is what I have, and it works mostly:

```
        If System.IO.File.Exists(sListItems) = True Then

            Dim writeToFile As New System.IO.StreamWriter(sListItems, True)

            writeToFile.WriteLine(vbCrLf & txtGameTitle.Text)
            writeToFile.Close()

        Else

            MsgBox("Error!")

        End If
    End If
```

The problem is with that, when I enter text such as 'Hello', it would instead put into the txt file 'Hello ' (with a space). Is there anyway to resolve this?

Comment: Not sure why the space is being added, but you can always apply .TrimEnd() to your txtGameTitle.Text.

Comment: @petryuno it's just `.Trim()`... Anyways just do this `txtGameTitle.Text.Trim()`. Also no need to check if the file is there, if it's not it will be created.

Comment: Don't use File.Exists()

Comment: @Zaggler I wrote .TrimEnd() because he specified he had a trailing whitespace and didn't say he wanted whitespace from the beginning removed. .Trim() removes characters from the beginning and end of the string.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Don't use `File.Exists()`. It's a race condition waiting to blow up, and it's slower. Instead, look for the `FileMode` that matches how you want to use the file; then handle the exception if it fails (you need to handle the exception anyway, because of the race condition potential mentioned earlier).

Additionally, if you have your `Using` blocks correct, you don't need to call `.Close()`.

```
Try
    Using fs As New FileStream(sListItems, FileMode.Open)
        fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End)
        Using sw As New StreamWriter(fs)
            sw.WriteLine(txtGameTitle.Text)
        End Using
    End Using
Catch ex As IOException
    MsgBox("Error! -- " & ex.Message)
End If
```

But I wonder if you *really* care that the file already exists, and all you really need to do is this:

```
File.AppendAllText(sListItems, txtGameTitle.Text)
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, I think I figured it out. I changed:

writeToFile.WriteLine()

to

writeToFile.Write()

and it no longer gives spaces.

Edit:

I know what my problem was, I was using lbGameList.SelectedItem.ToString() to find the name and it was giving me spaces, so I added .TrimEnd to it and it works now, thanks